# Android browser issue with Angular2 pipes

Tags: android, angular

I am seeing an issue with angular2 pipes on the stock android browser on my HTC M8. A screenshot of what I am seeing is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFmZH.png. Plunker to replicate is http://plnkr.co/edit/6wdKFD5Rk0V67dZEWuuE.

Any pipe is preventing the rest of the page from rendering. A remote JS console gives the error:

`"EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot redefine property: length in [\n    Date with pipe: {{dateVar | date }} in AppComponent@3:32]"`

Am I encountering a bug in Angular2 here?

Browser is the stock HTC browser called "Internet". Android version 5.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

In your plunker example, you only have a `numberVar:Number = 12.23542;`, you miss the `dateVar` variable

Comment: Oops, this was an artifact of my attempting to debug the issue. I have updated the plunker to add the variable back. In any case the issue was still present on the number var.

Comment: I have no error on Nexus4 and I don't replicate error on your plunker :/

Comment: I can't replicate this on my Nexus 5 in Chrome or in Chrome on the HTC. Just the browser called "Internet" which I believe is webkit based.